# Unmark all labels when show plotly figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I have this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 6))
fig = px.bar(df)
fig.show()
```

which show this output:
[image]

I would like the starting output unmark all the variables (or to add a button that unmark them), so this will be the starting output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight forward use of `update_traces()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 6))
fig = px.bar(df).update_traces(visible="legendonly")
fig.show()
```